# New version of TeXShop uses spacebar as "next page" instead of as "page down"

Tags: texshop, viewers

When looking at the pdf preview on my MacBook Pro, I used to get "pagedown" by pressing the spacebar, and "scroll down" by pressing the down arrow. I recently updated to version 3.45.2  and now both the down arrow and space bar jump to the next page. Very frustrating! Please help?

Comment: It seems that the actions of “space bar” and “page down” have been switched. This seems to be a bug in TeXShop and should be reported.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a but in the software not solvable here.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I am using is FN + up/down arrow. Holding the function key (lower left corner on my MacBook) and pressing the up and down arrow keys give the page up and down effect.